# How to execute install.sh under Big Sur?

Tags: terminal, command-line

I am quite a n00b on MacOS and it feels like it got worse with Big Sur.

I need to execute a .sh script to complete the [setup of a 3d party app](https://github.com/Dyalog/dyalog-jupyter-kernel/wiki/1.-Offline-usage). The instructions say to "execute install.sh"
The first obstacle I found was that the file did't have the -x attribute set, so "`sudo chmod +x ./install.sh`" did that. Yet, when I do "`sudo ./install.sh`" it barfs "`sudo: unable to execute ./install.sh: No such file or directory`"

The file exists:

```
ls -l install.sh  
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 mbaas  staff  740 14 Feb 12:44 install.sh
```

What am I missing?

### Additional details:

- first line of script has the usual shebang:

  `#!/bin/sh`
- according to [these](https://scriptingosx.com/category/command-line/) instructions, the following shows the association of sh-files:

```
readlink /var/select/sh
/bin/bash
```

- does that shell exist?

```
ls -l /bin/bash
-r-xr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  1296640  1 Jan  2020 /bin/bash
```

```
ls -l /bin/sh
rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  120912  1 Jan  2020 /bin/sh
```

That's interesting:

```
ls -lOe@ install.sh
ls: install.sh : No such file or directory
```

I thought I may have been in the wrong directory, so just to verify:

```
ls -l install.sh
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 mbaas  staff  757 14 Feb 18:08 install.sh
```

- and finally: `hexdump -Cv -n 32 install.sh`

```
00000000  23 21 2f 62 69 6e 2f 73  68 0d 0a 73 65 74 20 2d  |#!/bin/sh..set -|
00000010  65 0d 0a 0d 0a 42 41 53  45 44 49 52 3d 24 28 64  |e....BASEDIR=$(d|
00000020
```

Comment: The correct answer is to ask the authors of the 3rd party app. As they supply instructions then they had better be correct.

Comment: `sudo` or not - I tried both.

Comment: what does `ls -lOe@ install.sh` give you? How about `hexdump -Cv -n 32 install.sh`?

Comment: Can you rerun the command David proposed, but just type the `in` part of the file name and then use Tab to auto-complete?

Comment: tab toggles through the list of files (there is also an install.bat) and then also offers install.sh and when I then execute, it produces same output as before.

Comment: Ok, run `ls -lOe@ inst*` then and add to the question. Also, details matter: Is there really a space after the filename in `ls: install.sh : No such file or directory` or is this a copy/paste artefact?

Comment: Also, how did you download https://github.com/Dyalog/dyalog-jupyter-kernel in the first place? I just tried with `git clone https://github.com/Dyalog/dyalog-jupyter-kernel.git` and got an `install.sh` with the x attribute set.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Good guess with the hexdump (`0d 0a`) :-)

Comment: Have the files passed through a Windows system on the way to your Mac? They contain windows-style line endings which won't work in shell scripts.

Comment: Wow, THANKS! Stupid Windows CRLF was the culprit. git-cmdlind wasn't working, so I copied the folder from my Windows-machine (and downloaded git afterwards - because I was focused on getting the notebooks to work...  THAT will teach me something.  Great cooperative research!  If any of you wants to answer, I will happily accept & close the question!

Comment: You should accept the answer posted by jksoegaard. Often here at Ask Different, other users will post comments which help develop an answer. This is done without the expectation of receiving an increase in reputation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.sh` files are what is known as "shell scripts". Basically, when you run a `.sh` file, you're not executing that file directly - instead the contents of the file is given to a specific program as instructions to follow. That specific program is named in the first line of the `.sh` file prefixed by `#!`.

The error message you see means that the program specified by that first line of the file does not exist (at the given location). Essentially the shell script is incorrectly made.

If you have knowledge about the purpose of the script, and how your system is setup, you might be able to use a texteditor to change the file line of the file to point to the correct program - otherwise I would contact the supplier of the program and ask for updated files and instructions.

UPDATE: You have updated your question with the first part of the contents of the shell script. This makes it clear that the problem is that the first line of the script ends not with a normal newline symbol (LF), but rather a Windows-style newline consisting of two symbols (CR LF).

You can fix the line feeds in the file by running this command in the same folder as the shell script using the Terminal:

```
perl -pi -e 's/\r\n|\n|\r/\n/g' install.sh
```